# Output Dimension mismatch in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to train my cnn model on an image dataset of with per image of dimension 200 x 200 x 3.
The dimensions of my x_train is `(25290, 200, 200, 3)` and x_test has dimension `(7026, 200, 200, 3).`

I have already tried using `fit_generator` but the error still persists

Here is the model that I have built

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(200,200,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(50, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(25, kernel_size=6, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(5, kernel_size=16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(550))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(250))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
#model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(25))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(x_train, y_train,
           steps_per_epoch = int(ceil(float(len(x_train)//50))),
           epochs=1,
           verbose=1,
           validation_data=(x_val, y_val),callbacks=[monitor])
```

On runnning the model I am getting the following error

```
Error when checking target: expected activation_31 to have 2 dimensions, 
but got array with shape (25290, 2, 2)
```

Here activation_31 is the last layer of activation `model.add(Activation('softmax'))`

Comment: The labels need to have 2 dimensions and a shape of ( 25290, 2 ), since the last Dense layer has 2 units.

Comment: Check the dimension of your `y_train`. It should be `(number_of_samples,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, this is because of a mismatch between the number outputs from the network and the shape of y_train. You need to one-hot encode your training label set. Since your already using keras:

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical

y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
```

You can then run your `fit_generator` method.